# KDF options for a ECDH shared secret

Tags: aes, diffie-hellman, key-derivation

the answer to [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48047/can-a-raw-ecdh-shared-secret-be-used-directly-for-encryption) question suggests that the x-coordinate of an ECDH shared secret is itself usable as an encryption key **without** apply a KDF....  if so, then what additional security is provided by the KDF???

i'm operating in a very resource-constrained embedded environment, where eliminating code normally used in a KDF (eg., SHA256) is critical...  i should also add that ECDH private key is generated from a truly random 256-bit seed....

i'm already using 128-bit AES-CCM for encryption/authentication....  perhaps i can use the AES engine in some manner to "hash" the shared secret if that is advantageous....

that gives me three choices to produce a 128-bit AES key from my ECDH shared secret:

1. use the secret's x-coordinate (trimming its size)
2. applying a SHA-256 hash
3. using AES-CCM for hashing (with some known key/IV)

what are the tradeoffs here and are there any other options worth considering???

Comment: In this case, using KDF can only slow down the key-search. One can use both.