# Can a KEM shared secret be used directly as a symmetric key?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, kem

As an example, both Classic-McEliece and Kyber KEMs produce 32 byte shared secrets. How convenient since that's exactly the size I need for an AES-256 key!

Is this safe to do? My question can be formalized into these (I believe) equivalent questions about the definition of KEMs (I'm mostly interested in NIST Round 3 PQC KEMs, but more general answers are ok too)

1. Does an $X$-bit KEM shared secret contain $X$ bits of entropy?
2. Are the bits of a KEM shared secret guaranteed to be IID?
3. Can a KEM shared secret be used directly as a symmetric key?

---

*Background to explain how I arrived at this question; not actually part of the question.*

*I am expecting the answer to be "No, you need to run the SS though a KDF", but I'm looking for citations to back that up. That would align with this answer that @poncho gave about ECDH, which would also be true of DH, but maybe those are not formally KEMs?:*

- [Can a raw ECDH shared secret be used directly for encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48047/can-a-raw-ecdh-shared-secret-be-used-directly-for-encryption)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pass it through a KDF? Or are you just asking about the theory? Anyway I think those two algorithms you mentioned are actually defined as using a KDF to generate the shared secret.

Comment: @forest *can't* is a strong word, but it simplifies protocol design if I don't need a KDF as that's one more set of parameters I need to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithms you mentioned use a secure hash function to derive this convenient 32-byte shared secret, but it is not necessarily true that *all* KEMs will do so. The answer to your three general questions would thus be all "it depends on the actual algorithm". In general, they use KDFs.

The [Kyber KEM submission](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210131.pdf), for example, uses SHAKE-256:

> As a modification in round-2, we decided to **derive the final key using SHAKE-256** instead of SHA3-256. This is an advantage for protocols that need keys of more than 256 bits. Instead of first requesting a 256-bit key from Kyber and then expanding it, they can pass an additional key-length parameter to Kyber and obtain a key of the desired length. This feature is not supported by the NIST API, so **in our implementations we set the keylength to a fixed length of 32 bytes** in api.h.

The [McEliece submission](https://classic.mceliece.org/nist/mceliece-20190331.pdf) uses the same hash function:

> 3.1 Parameter set kem/mceliece348864
>
> KEM with $m = 12$, $n = 3488$, $t = 64$, $\ell = 256$.
>
> Field polynomial $f(z) = z^{12} + z^3 + 1$.
>
> Hash function: **SHAKE256 with 32-byte output.**
>
> This parameter set is proposed and implemented in this submission.